# Liferay Service Builder: Creating Finders That Match At Least One column

Tags: java, liferay-6

When generating entities in your service.xml through Liferay Service Builder, it is commonplace to create **finder** columns resembling the snippet below:

```
   <entity name="Person" local-service="true" >
        <column name="personId" type="long" primary="true" />
        <column name="firstName" type="String" />
        <column name="lastName" type="String" />
        <finder name="AnyName" return-type="Collection" >
            <finder-column name="firstName" />
            <finder-column name="lastName" />
        </finder>
   <entity>
```

This creates a finder method which can find entities which match both the **firstName** AND the **lastName**.

How can I create a finder which matches any of the columns optionally. I need something that generates SQL similar to : SELECT from person where firstName = "firstname" **OR** lastName = "lastname".

Is this possible?

Comment: directly through finder methods, it doesnt seems possible. you can utilize DynamicQuery here.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use DynamicQuery to use the 'OR' statement. Then another way I can think of is

adding this to service.xml

```
    <finder name="FirstName" return-type="Collection" >
        <finder-column name="firstName" />
    </finder>

    <finder name="LastName" return-type="Collection" >
        <finder-column name="lastName" />
    </finder>
```

And this to you PersonLocalServiceImpl

```
    public List < Person > getPersonByAnyName(String firstName, String lastName) {
        if (firstName != null && (lastName == null || lastName.equals("") )) {
            return getPersonByFirstName(firstName);
        }
        if (lastName != null && (firstName == null || firstName.equals("") )) {
            return getPersonByLastName(lastName);
        }

        return personPeristence.findByAnyName(firstName, lastName);

    }


    public List < Person > getPersonByFirstName(String firstName) {
        // return the Collection from personPersistence.findByFirstName ...
    }

    public List < Person > getPersonByLastName(String lastName) {
        // return the Collection from personPersistence.findByLastName ...
    }
```

Edit: oops, this code will not work as an OR statement, I works if you mean to use one of the Sting parameters as null

Comment: I think the DynamicQuery covers it